# Why some characters have different sounds?

Tags: characters, pronunciation, pinyin

My translator (Pleco) says that **乐** is pronunced as **le**. However, 音**乐** seems to be pronunced as yīn**yuè**.

Why? Is it possible to know if a character has different sounds depending on the context?

Comment: Yes, some characters have different pronunciations and different meanings. There are no hard rules for that, practically you need to learn and remember these one by one.

Comment: How do you do it in English?  That might give you a hint. produce, produce, refuse, refuse, read, read

Comment: Different sound means you are using another meaning of the character.
e.g. when you reference happy of 乐, you pronounce le4, when reference music of 乐, you pronounce yue4